# How to use a git repository to version control a whole website including databases that are made with phpmyadmin?

Tags: web-development, database, github, xampp, git

In the past I didn't use git and just created my web-projects local on my computer using XAMPP. By that I could create databases via phpmyadmin and simply save my other website files in the htdocs-folder (F:\xampp\htdocs). After that I just saw the result in my browser using localhost.

Now I want to version control my new web-project using git (I have learned the basics already). But the problem occurred that I don't know how to version control the whole website including my databases which are stored in a completely different folder (F:\xampp\mysql\data).

Do I have to version control the whole xampp folder? Or is it even possible to version control databases?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. The next time I'll ask my question about web development there. But the funny thing about that is that I wanted to post this question at Stack Overflow but after reading their FAQ I decided to post this question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To version control a whole project with its database, you could use a `mysqldump` to export the database in your `htdocs` directory before to commit it.

Comment: Okay, thank you! And if I switch to an old commit, do I just have to import the .sql-file?

Comment: Yep and you will recover the database at the same point as you backed up it.

Comment: Oh thank you a lot! You saved me a lot of time :D